# Execute a query foreach row from a result set.

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, cursor

I have a query that needs to be executed for each row in a result set. I understand that I need to do this with cursors, but I dont know how.

The first query contains customers with a specific condition, I need to retreive the Id:s from them.

The second query selects the latest activity from these customers.

Query 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Name, c.Id 
    FROM Persons p 
    JOIN Customers c ON c.id = p.Customer_Id 
    WHERE C.State = 3 AND c.SalesPerson_Id ='A3160011-CAA6-E411-A83E-AC7BA1B90A6D' AND c.Id NOT IN 
                                    ( 
                                    SELECT Distinct p.Customer_Id
                                    FROM Activities a
                                    JOIN Persons p
                                    ON a.Person_Id = p.Id
                                    WHERE a.[Type] IN (5,6) AND a.[Time] > getdate()-30 AND a.[Time] < getdate() 
                                    ) 
    AND c.id NOT IN 
                                    (
                                    SELECT  
                                    DISTINCT p.Customer_Id 
                                    FROM  
                                    Persons p
                                    JOIN HtmlEmails he ON p.Id = he.UserId
                                    JOIN ReportLog rl ON he.Id = rl.HtmlEmails_Id 
                                    WHERE rl.[Time] > getdate()-30 AND rl.[Time] < getdate())
```

Query 2

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
                    FROM(
                        SELECT TOP 1 c.Name AS 'CustomerName', c.Id AS 'CustomerId', a.[Time] AS 'LastActivity',(p.FirstName  + ' ' + p.LastName) AS 'UserFullName' , 'Login' AS 'Type'
                        FROM Activities a
                        JOIN Persons p ON p.Id = a.Person_Id
                        JOIN Customers c ON p.Customer_Id = c.Id
                        WHERE a.[Type] IN (5,6) AND a.[Time] < getdate()-30
                        ORDER BY a.[Time] DESC
                    UNION
                        SELECT TOP 1 c.Name AS 'CustomerName', c.Id AS 'CustomerId', a.[Time] AS 'LastActivity',(p.FirstName  + ' ' + p.LastName) AS 'UserFullName' , 'Email' AS 'Type' 
                        FROM Activities a
                        JOIN HtmlEmails he ON a.TargetId = he.Id
                        JOIN ReportLog rl on he.Id = rl.HtmlEmails_Id
                        JOIN Persons p ON p.Id = a.Person_Id
                        JOIN Customers c ON p.Customer_Id = c.Id
                        WHERE a.[Time] < getdate()-30
                        ORDER BY a.[Time] DESC
                        )AS x
    ORDER BY 'LastActivity' DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: What query are you running against what result set? All I see are two semi-related queries, what's your expected outcome?

Comment: I want to sort out customers from the first query and recieve a list of Id's. Then I want to run the second query for each Id from the first query.